# A question on encoding

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

Assuming there is a machine which can effectively calculate functions not computable by a TM (or the Church-Turing thesis as false) What can we say about aTM solving a problem encoded by this machine...

Q1.  Is there a not trivial example of a Turing decidable problem which still remains decidable once encoded with a non-Turing computable function?

Q2. Is there a counter example?

Answer (score 2):

Q1. The empty language is decidable however you encode it.

Q2. Represent the natural number $n$ as the encoding of the $n$th Turing machine that halts when started with a blank tape. Under this encoding, any set of natural numbers, except for $0$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is undecidable.

Comment: Thanks. For Q1 the empty language seems a trivial case as there is no decision to be made at all (as would be the set of all strings)

Comment: For Q2, won't finite and cofinite sets still remain decidable? I think some infinite, coinfinite sets remain decidable as well: let $M$ halt on blank tape. Then there exists a inf-coinf. set of naturals that once encoded becomes $ \{ \mathsf{pad}^i(\#M)\ |\ i\in\mathbb{N} \}$ which is decidable, where $\sf pad$ is a padding function.